# Openssl s_client and HERE documents

Tags: bash, openssl

All,
  I'm attempting to create a bash shell script that uses openssl to do an https query for me (/dev/tcp and wget are unavailable) along the lines of:

```
openssl s_client -connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port <<EOF
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
...more http here...


EOF
```

If I do the command line by hand, typing in the request, it works as expected and I see the correct HTML. However, if I run it from inside of a shell script I am not getting an HTTP document back from the server. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder whether `-ign_eof` helps. The original problem is described in http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg02926.html (note this is *very* old) and this switch seems to fit.

Comment: It was hanging after returning the input (since ignoring eof), so I added "Connection: close" so that the server closes the connection.